# AR Player (360 Videos)

Tags: augmented-reality, virtual-reality

I want to experiment with 360° videos and I have a little idea, but I don't know how I can solve this. I want to embed a video from a streed and want to display the street-names and want to draw colored lines on the roads. When I move the view of the video (I turn 45° as example) I want that the lines and street-names go with the video and always stay on their places.

Do you have a solution approach for me?

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want a 360 video with street names? It will be easiest to  just render everything on top of that video. You will need to render the AR layer as a equirectangular 360x180 video in some software like Blender and then merge it with the video you have with something like Adobe After Effects.

An alternative would be to do the AR layer in a 3d engine like Unity and put the video in the background.

It's hard to suggest you anything as what you're asking is very broad.